# Load a Kendo UI Grid into a hidden div?

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Has anyone loaded a Kendo UI Grid into a hidden div (e.g. `display:none;`)?

I've had issues trying to do it myself and am ending up with empty grids. Rebuilding the grid after the div is back on the screen solves it. Wondering how to load in the background.

Using the HTML5/JS framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what kind of problems you have but doesn't seem to be a problem if you do it as follow.

```
// initialize the grid as you are doing
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
});

// Show the grid
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.wrapper.css("display", "block");

// Hiding the grid
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.wrapper.css("display", "none");
```

Snippet example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.wrapper.css("display", "block");
  });
  
  
  $("#hide").on("click", function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.wrapper.css("display", "none");
  });
  
  
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            OrderID: { type: "number" },
            Freight: { type: "number" },
            ShipName: { type: "string" },
            OrderDate: { type: "date" },
            ShipCity: { type: "string" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 20,
      serverPaging: true,
      serverFiltering: true,
      serverSorting: true
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
      {
        field:"OrderID",
        filterable: false
      },
      "Freight",
      {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      }, 
      {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<button class="k-button" id="show">Show</button>
<button class="k-button" id="hide">Hide</button>
<div id="grid" style="display: none"></div>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what's going on. I tried to repro in a sandbox and have it working in a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Zacc206/ab4xbcjk/. When I try to do this in my solution, I get a grid that is buildling without any data. Really weird. I'll look into the JS and see if there is something else going on and share what I find.

Comment: Nice solution.. page buttons are not getting displayed in grid2 if I load two different grids in two divs and toggle div's style from block to none. "grid.wrapper.css" solved the issue.